# Superscript or subscript in TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="50" FontFamily="Segoe UI">
    <Run>Normal Text</Run>
    <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="Superscript123"/>
    <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript" Text="Subscript123"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Below is my screen shot. It seems that certain characters are not allowed in super/sub script.
[image]

Actually I want to put a **®** symbol what I'm getting is

[image]

and what I want is

[image]

**P.S.** I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3435675/468724 but there is no such property as `BaselineAlignment`

Comment: it will depend on the font used as to what variants are supported - Palatino Linotype supports all the letters for instance.  If you use FontFamily=Segoe WP for the registration mark you'll get the desired behavior, but I'm not sure if you can/want to rely on Segoe WP being on the device.

Comment: @JimO'Neil Yeah that I got that it depends upon font family. But what about baseline property???

Comment: The other question was related to WPF. WPF is a granddad of WinRT/XAML present in Windows 8 and used for Windows Store Apps.

Comment: @FilipSkakun yeah you are right but is there any property/solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `Segoe WP` font

Or can do like this

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="16" Text"Normal Text"/>
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="9" Text="&#174;"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I used 60% lesser font for trademark symbol

Answer (score 0):

This looks nice for a subscsript Run in a TextBlock on my screen, using VS2015:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Run}" x:Key="Sub">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>        
    <Setter Property="BaselineAlignment" Value="TextBottom"/>
</Style>
```

It's just a bit lower than Typography.Variants = Subscript, which seems to use just a smaller font