# How to Superscript some Text in a TextBox/TextBlock Control in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm working on windows phone 8 app, and m stuck here, guys i want to show some text as a superscript either in TextBox or in TextBlock where-ever possible. suggest me how can i obtained it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a stackpanel wrapping a couple of textblocks instead?  Then adjust the margines on the stuff you want super and subscripted.

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="H2O3" FontSize="40" Margin="0,10"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="H" FontSize="40" />
            <TextBlock Text="2" FontSize="40" Margin="0,-20,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="O" FontSize="40"/>
            <TextBlock Text="3" FontSize="40" Margin="0,10,0,-10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: NP.  Go through a grinder a few times,  you get it.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative but it's only available in WP8: [Typography.Variants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.documents.typography.variants%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

I personally prefer this approach as it aligns more with WPF but there are cases where you have to do baseline manipulation or in this instance, margin wrangling. If WPF is any indication, it also requires a font that supports variants which are generally open type/true type only. See [Superscript / subscript in hyperlink in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252114/superscript-subscript-in-hyperlink-in-wpf) for a better explanation.