# Displaying superscirpt character in textblock ( windows phone) programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, textblock

I am new to Windows phone development. I need to display a superscript character in textblock.
ex: 60S
- 'S' should be display as superscript. How to do it  programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You may find your answer by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147423/how-to-superscript-some-text-in-a-textbox-textblock-control-in-windows-phone-8). There is not a direct way to do that but you may create a stackpanel. Then you can have several TexTBlocks in your StackPanel. The only thing that you need to do is change the Position of different TextBlocks inside the StackPanel.