# Superscript + Underline inline in a RichTextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, superscript

I have a set of text that I'd like to put in a RichTextBox which goes like so:

[image: Result I want to see]

So I used a RichTextBox since it allows me to do the following.

```
var zipCodeParagraph = new Paragraph();
string zipCodes = String.Empty;

var dateRun = new Underline(new Run(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + ", " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(DateTime.Today.Month) + ' ' + DateTime.Today.Day));
Underline dateSuperscript;

switch (DateTime.Today.Day % 10)
{
    case 1:
        dateSuperscript = new Underline(new Run("st"));
        break;
    case 2:
        dateSuperscript = new Underline(new Run("nd"));
        break;
    case 3:
        dateSuperscript = new Underline(new Run("rd"));
        break;
    default:
        dateSuperscript = new Underline(new Run("th"));
        break;
}

dateSuperscript.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Superscript;

if (ZipCodes.Any())
{
    zipCodeParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("The following zip codes are facing a "));
    zipCodeParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Underline(new Run("Severe Weather Threat")));
    zipCodeParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(" on "));
    zipCodeParagraph.Inlines.Add(dateRun);
    zipCodeParagraph.Inlines.Add(dateSuperscript);
    zipCodes = String.Join(", ", ZipCodes.ToArray());
}
```

The outcome however is like so:

[image: Result I am getting]

The problem is that when changing the baseline of a text to be superscript/subscript then the underline changes to that height as well. I'd like the underline to stay where it is and for the super-scripting to happen as well.

I have found only one close solution which does not do it programmatically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252114/superscript-subscript-in-hyperlink-in-wpf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to convert the same code which is mentioned in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252114/superscript-subscript-in-hyperlink-in-wpf).
Refer the below code.

```
   FlowDocument mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
        Hyperlink hyp = new Hyperlink();
        hyp.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
        txt.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        txt.Text = "Friday,April 10";           
        Run rn = new Run("th");
        rn.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Superscript;
        txt.Inlines.Add(rn);
        hyp.Inlines.Add(txt);            
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        para.Inlines.Add(new Run("The following zip codes are facing a "));
        para.Inlines.Add(new Underline(new Run("Severe Weather Threat")));
        para.Inlines.Add(new Run(" on "));
        para.Inlines.Add(hyp); 
        mcFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
        RichTextBox mcRTB = new RichTextBox();
        mcRTB.Width = 560;
        mcRTB.Height = 100;
        mcRTB.Document = mcFlowDoc;
```

Answer (score 1):

As this seems a limitation of the RichTextBox, the best solution would be the one proposed in the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17489796/259206) of the question you linked, namely instead of using the normal letters, to use their [Unicode superscript variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts):

"st" becomes "ˢᵗ"
"nd" becomes "ⁿᵈ"

etc.

You should also remove the baseline setting:

```
//dateSuperscript.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Superscript;
```