# C# RichTextBox define Colors for multiple lines

Tags: c#, controls, richtextbox

is it possible to define forecolors for multiple lines in a RichTextBox?

I am only able to do something like this:

```
tb.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

-> The text of all lines will be red.

What i want to do is to set a different color for every line.
For example: line1: blue, line2: green, line3: yellow

Following problem:

```
foreach (var line in tb.Lines)
{

}
```

While defining tb.Lines == 0, so i can´t define colors for the single lines...

Comment: Set the new SelectionColor and/or whatever styling you need instead of the SelectionBackColor in  the link!

Comment: Where is a duplicate?`Can you post the link?

Comment: The link is up on top. It leads to a post that lets you color a line by number.

Comment: If you have questions feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the inlines definition in RichTextBox in order to define how the text has to be formatted

see this link to a
[stackoverflow old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038991/superscript-underline-inline-in-a-richtextbox-in-wpf)
for how to do it in a RichTextBox

Comment: This is not about a textblock.